# Calculate the average for each category, and fill in missing values with this average

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm newish to `r` and trying to solve a basic problem.

I have a tibble called `books`. One of these columns is `total_purchased` (total number of books purchased) and another is `title` (title of the book).

Within the `total_purchased` column there are a number of missing values. I want to replace these with the average purchase quantity for each book. However, I can't really get this working in an efficient way. Below I've just hardcoded the names of the books in.

So for example, I

1. Filter the tibble where the `total_purchased` column consists of `na` values, and by book `title`.
2. Calculate the `mean`.
3. Perform these steps separately for each book.
4. Use the `mutate` function to add a new column which is just a copy of `total_purchased`, except it assigns the relevant mean to each `na` value.

I basically just need to understand how I can simplify this so I'm not hardcoding book titles in, and also reduce the amount of code. I'm just a bit too unfamiliar with `r` to work it out myself. In another language, I would be utilising loops here, but unsure if there's some vectorisation I can use which will do this simply.

```
# Calculate mean total purchased for particular book.
SOR <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "Secrets Of R For Advanced Students") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean

RFD <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "R For Dummies") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean
FOR <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "Fundamentals of R For Beginners") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean
RVP <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "R vs Python: An Essay") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean
TTM <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "Top 10 Mistakes R Beginners Make") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean
RME <- books %>%
                  filter(!(is.na(total_purchased))) %>%
                  filter(title == "R Made Easy") %>%
                    pull(total_purchased) %>%
                      mean

# Assign mean specific to book when total purchased value is na
books <- books %>%
                    mutate(complete_purchased = case_when(
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "Secrets Of R For Advanced Students" ~ SOR,
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "R For Dummies" ~ RFD,
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "Fundamentals of R For Beginners" ~ FOR,
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "R vs Python: An Essay" ~ RVP,
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "Top 10 Mistakes R Beginners Make" ~ TTM,
                      is.na(total_purchased) & title == "R Made Easy" ~ RME,
                      TRUE ~ total_purchased
                    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the tidyverse. I created some dummy data to demonstrate.

You can calculate the mean for a group using `mutate`, and then we can create the replacement column using `ifelse`

```
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(id = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                  y = sample(c(NA, 1:2), 10, replace = TRUE))

dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(y_mean = mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(y_replace = ifelse(is.na(y), y_mean, y))

 #   id        y y_mean y_replace
 #   <chr> <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
 # 1 a         2    1.5       2  
 # 2 c        NA    1         1  
 # 3 a        NA    1.5       1.5
 # 4 b        NA    1.5       1.5
 # 5 a         1    1.5       1  
 # 6 c         1    1         1  
 # 7 c         1    1         1  
 # 8 b         1    1.5       1  
 # 9 b         2    1.5       2  
 #10 c        NA    1         1
```

One-liner in base R using `ave`:

```
ifelse(is.na(dat$y), ave(dat$y, dat$id, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), dat$y)
# [1] 2.0 1.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 1.0
```

Comment: FYI, you can do this in the same `mutate()` call

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `dplyr`, which probably has a nice solution for it, but using loops you can go through each unique title:

```
for(i in unique(books$title)){
  title.index = books$title==i
  condition = is.na(books$total_purchased) &  title.index
  title.mean = mean(books$total_purchased[title.index])
  books$total_purchased[condition] = title.mean}
```

Obs: you can write the whole code into a single line, i broke it into variables to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. Although wouldn't something like `books$total_purchased[title.index]` just throw an error, or not return anything? As the column `total_purchased` doesn't contain the titles.

Comment: Post your data (paste the output of `dput(your_data)`) so i can check what's wrong